# bash: /root/bin/hello_world: Permission denied

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, permissions

I am using the CentOS 7.

1. I wrote my first bash script like this.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo 'this is my first code'
   ```

   and I saved it as *hello_world*
2. I made a directory in my root home directory.

   ```
   mkdir bin
   ```
3. Then I moved the script to the `~/bin` directory.
4. Then I did this:

   ```
   export PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"
   source ~/bin
   ```
5. Then I tried to run the script with the below command.

   ```
   hello_world
   ```

but I did not see the `this is my first code` but I got a `bash: /root/bin/hello_world: Permission denied` error instead.

Comment: oh no, i forgot to grant the proper right to this file. thank you Muru

Comment: Note also, that `source ~/bin` doesn't make sense. From the context, we see that `bin` must be a directory, and you can't *source* a directory.

Comment: +1 for extually including all relevant information in the question and not just saying "It doesn't work" like many others do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a script to be executable without executing it with an explicit interpreter (as in `bash ~/bin/hello_world`), the script file has to have its "executable bit" set.  This is done with `chmod` (see its manual):

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/hello_world
```

This sets the executable bit for the owner of the file.

Or,

```
chmod +x ~/bin/hello_world
```

This sets the executable bit according to your current `umask`.  Assuming that your `umask` is `022` (a common default), this will make it executable for all users.

---

The `source` step that you did is nonsense and should have given you an error message (you can't source a directory).

If you need the setting of the new `PATH` to be "permanent", then add the `export PATH` line to your shell's startup file (`~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash` as your interactive shell).

---

Also, avoid working at an interactive root prompt. Use an unprivileged user account for testing and exploring, and use `sudo` from that account for those few times that you need to do administrative tasks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Fixed it.